# run second jq click function after run first jq click in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that by clicking on it, its function is performed in different places by two  `$(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function () {`. I want the first `jq` to be activated after the second `jq`.

Friends, can you help if there is a way to do this?

note:I can not change the first `jq`

Is there a way to detect with `jq2` only that jq1 is activated and jq2 is activated after the end of jq1function?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function() { // first jq
  console.log("Good day")
});
$(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function() { //second jq
  console.log("hello")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="lm_tabs"> me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more tabs, then you need to set a flag on each tab

```js
// Original code
$(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function() {
  console.log("old event handler")
});

// your code

const func1 = (str) => console.log("Hello",str);
const func2 = (str) => console.log("Good day",str);

$(document).off('click', '.lm_tabs'); // the magic

$(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function() {
  const active = $(this).data("clicked") === "yes";
  func1(this.id); // you can test active here too to NOT execute func1 again
  if (active) func2(this.id)
  $(this).data("clicked", "yes");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="lm_tabs" id="me1"> me</button> and <button class="lm_tabs" id="me2"> me</button>
```

Comment: brilliant, this will make it more dynamic!

Comment: thank@mplungjan . but I can not change the first jq.Is there a way to detect with` jq2` only that  `jq1` is activated and `jq2` is activated after the end of  `jq1`function?

Answer (score 1):

you could do that by creating a variable that saves the first action like this

```js
 let isClicked = false;

 $(document).on('click', '.lm_tabs', function () {// first jq
        if(!isClicked){
            console.log("Good day")
            isClicked = true;
        } else {
           console.log("hello")        
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="lm_tabs"> me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning that check it again please